# Change datatype of primary key of all tables in database

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key, sqldatatypes

Consider having a database with 50+ tables, with a moderate amount of foreign key relationships.
Every table in the database has numeric datatype as the primary key column.  Is there any way to change the datatype of all primary key columns from numeric to VARCHAR given that the database remains intact and all foreign key relationships too.

Note:- Postgresql is used as RDBMS.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why change from numeric to varchar? If at all I would change from numeric to bigint.

Comment: not varchar actually, want to use UUID

Comment: Then you should have written that ;)

Comment: Yeah that's true

Answer (score 3):

This is going to be very complicated because you need to generate a new UUID for each existing PK value. I suggest to do this in several steps:

1. add a `uuid` column (**not** varchar please!) to each table as not null with a default value that generates the uuid.
2. create a unique index for each of the "new pk" columns
3. for those tables referencing other tables create new FK columns of type uuid (without the FK yet).
4. for each table referencing the just created UUIDs use an UPDATE statement to store the generated PK value in the new uuid foreign key column
5. drop the old primary and foreign key constraints
6. recreate the primary keys with the `using index` option specifying the unique indexes created in step 2
7. recreate the foreign keys pointing to the new uuid columns
8. drop the old numeric (pk and fk) columns
9. rename the new columns to the names of the old columns

Something like the following:

Setup sample tables and insert data:

```
create table one (id integer primary key);
create table two (id integer primary key);
create table three (id integer primary key, one_id integer references one);
create table four (id integer primary key, two_id integer references two);
create table five (id integer primary key, three_id integer references three);

insert into one values (1),(2),(3);
insert into two values (10),(20),(30);
insert into three (id, one_id) values (100,1),(200,2),(300,3);
insert into four (id, two_id) values (1000, 10), (2000, 20), (3000, 30);
insert into five (id, three_id) values (10000, 100), (20000, 200), (30000, 300);
```

Add the new `uuid` columns and populate the new PK columns through the default value.

```
alter table one 
  add column new_id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4();
create unique index one_new_pkey on one (new_id);  

alter table two add column new_id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4();
create unique index two_new_pkey on two (new_id);  

alter table three add column new_id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4(), 
                  add column new_one_id uuid;
create unique index three_new_pkey on three (new_id);  

alter table four add column new_id uuid not null  default uuid_generate_v4(), 
                 add column new_two_id uuid;
create unique index four_new_pkey on four (new_id);  

alter table five add column new_id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4(), 
                 add column new_three_id uuid;
create unique index five_new_pkey on five(new_id);
```

Update the new foreign key columns with the generated IDs

```
update three 
  set new_one_id = one.new_id
from one 
where one.id = three.one_id;

update four 
  set new_two_id = two.new_id
from two
where two.id = four.two_id;

update five 
  set new_three_id = three.new_id
from three
where five.three_id = three.id;
```

Replace the old primary keys (removing any foreign key)

```
alter table one drop constraint one_pkey cascade;
alter table one add primary key using index one_new_pkey;

alter table two drop constraint two_pkey cascade;
alter table two add primary key using index two_new_pkey;

alter table three drop constraint three_pkey cascade;
alter table three add primary key using index three_new_pkey;

alter table four drop constraint four_pkey cascade;
alter table four add primary key using index four_new_pkey;

alter table five drop constraint five_pkey cascade;
alter table five add primary key using index five_new_pkey;
```

Create the new foreign keys

```
alter table three add constraint fk_three_one 
   foreign key (new_one_id)
   references one;

alter table four add constraint fk_four_two
   foreign key (new_two_id)
   references two;

alter table five add constraint fk_five_three
   foreign key (new_three_id)
   references three;
```

Get rid of the old columns that are not needed any longer

```
alter table one drop column id; 
alter table one rename column new_id to id;

alter table two drop column id; 
alter table two rename column new_id to id;

alter table three drop column id, drop column one_id; 
alter table three rename column new_id to id;
alter table three rename column new_one_id to one_id;

alter table four drop column id, drop column two_id; 
alter table four rename column new_id to id;
alter table four rename column new_two_id to two_id;

alter table five drop column id, drop column three_id; 
alter table five rename column new_id to id;
alter table five rename column new_three_id to three_id;
```

If you have consistent naming conventions it might be possible to automate this using dynamic SQL

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually there are 50+  tables. it would be easier if a script can do it with a loop or something like that and not just a naive approach.

Comment: Well, use this idea and create that script. Either using dynamic SQL or by generating the necessary statements e.g. from within a programming language. This is not something that other people can do for you.